# decrypt data in view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC4, i made Edit function and passed data to View from Controller, but data encrypted. I don't know how to decrypt data back when show it in View.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have written a function to encrypt and decrypt. and then insert data to Database, i used my encrypt. So in form Edit (View), how can i call decrypt function to decrypt back?

Comment: how do you encrypt the username? Could you provide the code?

Comment: I use RijndaelSimple Library to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Edit your question to add the code, not in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `getDecrypt_Account(string sParam)` on your edit(get) action to decrypt the data, then passes to the view. Something like:

```
@using Your.Decrypt.Method.Path;

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    User user = new Repository().GetUser(id);

    return View(new EditViewModel()
    {
        Code = user.Code,
        UserName = getDecrypt_Account(user.UserName),
        FullName = user.FullName
    });
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string setEncrypt_Account(string sParam)
        {
            sParam = Core_App.RijndaelSimple.Encrypt(sParam, "pr@se_AccPwd", "cts@devteam", "MD5", 2, "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8", 256);
            return sParam;
        }
        public static string getDecrypt_Account(string sParam)
        {
            sParam = Core_App.RijndaelSimple.Decrypt(sParam, "pr@se_AccPwd", "cts@devteam", "MD5", 2, "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8", 256);
            return sParam;
        }
```